# .net core 2.1 sharing migrations between multiple projects

Tags: .net, .net-core, migration, asp.net-core-2.1

Not exactly to sure how to handle this but I need multiple projects to access the same database tables, however, in .net core tables are normally created using migration files is there a way to share these migrations between multiple projects? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your context and entities into a class library, migrate against the class library, share the context and entities with other projects via project reference. The migrations should stay with your entities. No need to share, nor should you.